# outlook doing remote portscanning

Tags: firewall, email-server, outlook, nmap, port-scanning

A while ago I switched my mailbox on another domain and configured outlook with an exchange server on that domain.

Recently for some strange reason my hosting provider has been complaining that outlook runs regular portscans on his servers targeting port 25 and his firewall blacklisted my ip.

I've used tcp view and I see outlook on 3 different computers running the scame portscan on the remote server.

I've done an antivirus scan with eset but the computers are clean.

What's wrong in outlook that's causing the portscanning on the old server ?

Comment: Well technically it's not a port scan, it's Outlook attempting to do something, their firewall is just categorizing it as a port scan. Do the Outlook clients have multiple accounts configured, with the old server settings in there? One thing that would likely give you a lot of information is a packet capture with Wireshark on one of the PCs running Outlook. That would show exactly what connection was being made and what it was doing.

Comment: Outlook doesn't conduct port scans. Outlook is trying to connect via SMTP to your hosting providers server(s). What SMTP server or servers is Outlook configured to use (multiple SMTP servers if Outlook is configured with multiple accounts)?

Comment: nope Outlook has only got one exchange account and is on a different server.  There are no other options configured.  that's why its quite strange  and I didn't find any of the server settings ; looking at the account settings.     Is there another place where I should look for them ?